# UpdateAutoScalingGroup permission error with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

i am getting error while running this script :

```
def set_asg_launch_template_version_latest(asg_name, lt_id):
    try:
        response = client.update_auto_scaling_group(
            AutoScalingGroupName=asg_name,
            LaunchTemplate={
                'LaunchTemplateId': lt_id,
                'Version': '$Latest'
            }
        )
        print("Set launch template: {} version for asg: {} to $Latest".format(lt_id, asg_name))
        return response
    except ClientError as e:
        print('Error setting launch template version to $Latest')
        raise e
set_asg_launch_template_version_latest(ASGName,launch_template_id )
```

============>
ClientError - An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the UpdateAutoScalingGroup operation: You are not authorized to use launch template: lt-xxxxxxxxx

hint :
all these permissions are authorized (check last one):

```
        - resource-groups:ListGroupResources
        - tag:GetResources
        - s3:PutObject
        - s3:PutObjectAcl
        - s3:List*
        - ec2:Describe*
        - ec2:CreateSnapshot
        - ec2:CreateImage
        - kms:CreateGrant
        - ec2:StartInstances
        - ec2:RunInstances
        - ec2:TerminateInstances
        - autoscaling:StartInstanceRefresh
        - ec2:CreateSecurityGroup
        - ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress
        - ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup
        - ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress
        - ec2:ModifyLaunchTemplate
        - ec2:CreateLaunchTemplateVersion
        - autoscaling:Describe*
        - ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions
        - ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplates
        - autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup
```

Comment: Try adding `iam:PassRole`. It allows instances to be launched with an IAM Role attached. But be careful -- it can allow users to gain permissions from IAM Roles that might grant them Admin-like powers, so it's generally a good idea to limit _which_ roles they can use. But, start with granting all roles, just to see if it fixes your problem. See: [Reddit - API: autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup You are not authorized to use launch template : aws](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/cwya1p/api_autoscalingupdateautoscalinggroup_you_are_not/)

Comment: Can you share your full policy? From where are you running this script?

Comment: Yes it is PassRole issue :)
thank ou